# How to set custom fill color in dygraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, fill, dygraphs

By setting the property `fillGraph: true` , we can fill the dygraph with its default color. But how to fill it with a custom color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fill color is always the same as the series color (which you can control via the [`colors`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#colors) option) but with a lower opacity, controllable by the [`fillAlpha`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#fillAlpha) option.

If you need more flexibility than this, you have two options:

1. Create two series, one with fill and one without. You can use CSS to hide one from the legend. Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/2727/).
2. Create a custom plotter that uses the colors you want. Read more about how to do that [here](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/08/introducing-custom-plotters.html).